# Set IsDefault property to button in XAML/C# WinRT app

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

WPF XAML apps have had an [`IsDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) property for buttons so the `Enter` key will click a particular button by default.  How can we do this in a Windows Run Time application?

```xml
 <Button Name="SubmitButton" Content="Enter" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to generate this yourself unfortunately, there is no built in property.  Subscribe to the keydown event on the parent control and listen for the enter key to be hit, then execute your event.

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
{
}
```

Comment: you can also create an attachable behavior to wrap this functionality